# What would be the preferred data structure for a graphql resolver to return the counts of ratings?

Tags: data-structures, graphql-js

View :

[image]

Json that I return from the graphql field resolver.
The json is direct response of the sql query:

[image]

The front-end dev says the following:

[image]
[image]

To which I responded:

[image]

I feel this is case of overengineering and it is the responsibility of view to convert and use the data according to their view needs. I understand the need of caching the counts to optimize the query response and it has nothing to do with the arrray vs json format. The front-end dev wasn't convinced by my response and thinks this will cause performance issue and I'm failing to understand it and he has asked me to seek opinions from the stackoverflow community. Your enlightenment on this would be appreciated. I'd learn something out of it maybe. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the small amount of data like this, it's not a issue from view side to render. As per my perspective for the object and array structures, One should go for the object case in these scenarios. because currently ratings are displayed by stars, what if in the future it will be converted into graphs or other kind of representations.

In those cases the change will be required from both side as you have tightly coupled your view into server side logic. If you go with object, that will be only from view side and server will be independent from view.

Not only objects give you decouple environment, but in the future if you want to add some extra information, it will be easy for both the views. currently it's only number specific, what if in the future, view needs more information based on some profile like users, areas, eventually you will need to convert that into these structures. so, It would be more fruitful if you go with objects.

From the front side, if you want to optimize you can use memorize function with dependencies or normalization of objects, which will help the view to not the process that
much.

For the logic of reducer function to convert them into array, it's some what over operations, assuming find method does linear scan and your data is sorted so, find method quite reaches to 15 for five data(best case). You can go with sorting, it's roughly completes to 11, and you get more efficiency and scalability compare to normal array. since most of the sorting methods accept custom function to sort.

Any correction or other more options would be highly appreciated.